# VBA - determine if two or more cells overlap in the same cell address

Tags: vba, excel, loops, overlap

I have a worksheet with filled colored cells within certain borders, and I have to "move" the filled cells randomly by an offset provided by `NewX` and `NewY` parameters, select the new cell, delete the filling of the "old" cell and fill the new cell with a different color.

The problems start after I perform a few runs - it seems that the cells "disappear" - less and less cells are seen with time, and I assume it's because some of them ***overlap*** each other and since my code is set to find filled cells only and move them, their number decreases with time.

This is the code I'm using to move the filled cells:

```
Sub Move_Cells()

 For k = 1 to 20 'number of runs to perform the determination and movement of cells

  For i = 1 To 20 'the number can change due to borders
   For j = 1 To 20 'the number can change due to borders
     If Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
       x = j
        Y = i
       Randomize
        dX = Int((5 - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1)
       Randomize
        dY = Int((5 - 1 + 1) * Rnd() + 1)

         NewX = x + dX
          NewY = Y + dY

           Cells(NewY, NewX).Select
             Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 0

              Selection.Interior.Color = 3
 next k

End Sub
```

My concern is, the more times that you run the loop of `i,j`, more `Cells(NewY, NewX).Select` selections overlap, and thus determines less filled cells.

I was thinking about using the `Cells.Address` feature to determine beforehand if any cells overlap in their `(NewY, NewX)` position and avoid them to do so.

My other thought was to somehow split any cell that contains several addresses from other cells' offset to their original number, but I'm not that the `Split` feature is suitable for this situation. Is there any way to do that?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: You should only call `Randomize` ***once*** - all it does is set the initial seed for the RNG.  If you call it twice in quick secession, it's possible you'll get the same seed back.

Comment: You are correct when you say that the cells will overlap.  Every time you are selecting a new cell, you could be selecting a cell which is **already** coloured, thus effectively "losing" a cell.  Even if the source and destination areas didn't overlap, it would still be possible that the same destination cell could be selected for two source cells.  To avoid that, you will need to check the destination cell and, if it is already coloured, choose another destination cell (and keep doing so until you find one that isn't coloured).

Comment: Note:  If I read the intent of your code correctly, after 20 iterations you will be ending up with no coloured cells in A1:T20, and lots of coloured cells in (U1:Y25, A21:T25) - is that really what you intended?

Comment: I don't see any cell containing address in your code, you are only changing color of the cells. What do you mean by ` split any cell that contains several addresses`?

Comment: @YowE3K: there are many restrictions in that code that I hadn't put on here because they don't matter - but the bottom line is that all of the cells are kept within the 20x20 limits all the time.

Comment: @Vincent G: by splitting I mean that if I determine 2 cells that get the same "NewX NewY" address, then I would split them and turn them into 2 colored cells, that's why I asked if it's possible to do so.

Comment: Your code only add offset in range 1-6, so [A1] will move somewhere in [B2:G7] and so on. After 20 loops all your moved cells will be after [U21], and none will stay in range [A1:T20].

Comment: @Vincent G: as I mentioned in the comment below your first one, I have many restrictions on the code and all of the cells always stay within certain limits, but that code is really long and unnecessary but you should know that I have limits there.

Comment: Ok, to me it looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), and I don't think you posted enough code to infer your real needs.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that I think your phrasing in the question and comments has muddied our understanding of what you need.

As I see it, you want to select a single coloured cell and offset it randomly by up to 5 rows and 5 columns. You then want to fill the new cell red and the old cell clear. A restriction is that the new, randomly picked cell cannot be a red one. Is that right?

If so, then a way of managing the task is to create a range that only contains clear cells and randomly pick one cell from that range. To do this, you need to make use of the `Union` and `Intersect` functions. If you're not familiar with these, then you'll discover that quite a lot of care needs to be taken in checking for an 'uninstantiated' object (ie it is `Nothing`). In the code below, I've put a couple of helper functions that manage this checking for you.

The main routine, though, shows how you could handle this random selection and colour change. You'll need to add your own error handling should there be no red cells or unacceptable ranges:

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim border As Range
    Dim cell As Range, newCell As Range
    Dim filled As Range, blanks As Range
    Dim n As Long, i As Long

    'Define range of matrix
    Set border = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:T20")

    'Find the coloured cells
    For Each cell In border.Cells
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            Set filled = Add(filled, cell)
        End If
    Next

    Randomize

    For i = 1 To 100
        'Generate a random index of the filled cells
        n = Int(filled.Count * Rnd + 1)
        Set cell = CellAt(filled, n)

        'Find the blank cells within 5 of the filled cell
        Set blanks = FindBlanks(border, filled, cell, 5)

        'Generate a random index of the blank cells
        n = Int(blanks.Count * Rnd + 1)
        Set newCell = CellAt(blanks, n)

        'Repaint the cells
        cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        newCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

        'Swap cells
        Set filled = Remove(filled, cell)
        Set filled = Add(filled, newCell)

    Next
End Sub

Private Function FindBlanks(border As Range, _
                            filled As Range, _
                            target As Range, _
                            limit As Integer) As Range
    Dim topRow As Long
    Dim bottomRow As Long
    Dim leftCol As Long
    Dim rightCol As Long
    Dim rng As Range


    With border
        topRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(target.Row - 5, .Rows(1).Row)
        bottomRow = WorksheetFunction.Min(target.Row + 5, .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row)
        leftCol = WorksheetFunction.Max(target.Column - 5, .Columns(1).Column)
        rightCol = WorksheetFunction.Min(target.Column + 5, .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column)

        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(topRow, leftCol), .Cells(bottomRow, rightCol))
    End With

    Set FindBlanks = Remove(rng, filled)

End Function

Private Function CellAt(rng As Range, index As Long) As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Long

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        i = 1
        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            If i = index Then
                Set CellAt = cell
                Exit Function
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End If
End Function

Private Function Add(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Range
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then
        If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
            Set Add = rng2
        End If
    Else
        If rng2 Is Nothing Then
            Set Add = rng1
        Else
            Set Add = Union(rng1, rng2)
        End If
    End If
End Function

Private Function Remove(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        If rng2 Is Nothing Then
            Set Remove = rng1
        Else
            For Each cell In rng1.Cells
                If Intersect(cell, rng2) Is Nothing Then
                    Set Remove = Add(Remove, cell)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the code and the work you have put in. I must say that I'm sorry that I wasn't clear enough about my intentions and purpose of the code, and you misunderstood me as well. It has nothing to do with the color of the cell - it's just that many cells usually overlap each other and create one red cell instead of being 2,3 or more separate cells.

Comment: Ok, I think you'd be best to submit a new question. Try to avoid phrases like overlapping or split, as it isn't really clear what you mean. I still don't understand what you're asking and I'm probably not alone. Be as specific as you can, ie give examples of ranges or show images of what the sheets look like (both before and after). I suspect your coding problem will be easily fixed, we just need you to articulate that problem as clearly as you possibly can.