# VBA - Error when using values of a 2D array to fill cells

Tags: arrays, vba, multidimensional-array

I am using an array in VBA to loop through a defined range of 10x10, find each of the 5 filled cells within it, and assign a column, row, column offset, row offset and color index for each of these cells, using a 10x5 array.

Once a filled cell is found, it gets a new position using its column/row with the appropriate offset, erases the original found cells and fill the new ones.

However, when I tried using the array values for the new cell to fill it, I get a ***1004 error*** - application-defined/object defined error.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Sub FindCells()

Dim i As integer, j As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim NewX As Integer, NewY As Integer     

'this is the array I'm using
Dim Molecules() As Variant
ReDim Molecules(1 To 5, 1 To 5)    '1 to 5 - number of filled cells
                                     '1 to 5 - positions, offsets and color index

 For i = 1 To UBound(Molecules)
   For j = 1 To UBound(Molecules, 2)

     For Each c In Worksheets("Main Screen")

       If c.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then

        Randomize
        dX = Int((H - L + 1) * Rnd() + L)   'speed vector x
        dY = Int((H - L + 1) * Rnd() + L)    'speed vector y

        Molecules(i, 1) = c.Column
        Molecules(i, 2) = c.Row
        Molecules(i, 3) = dX
        Molecules(i, 4) = dY
        Molecules(i, 5) = c.Interior.ColorIndex

        'new position of the cells
        NewX = Molecules(i, 1) + Molecules(i, 3)
        NewY = Molecules(i, 2) + Molecules(i, 4)

      End If
     Next c

     'the array gets the new position values
     Molecules(i, 1) = NewX
     Molecules(i, 2) = NewY

     'now color the new found cells
     Cells(Molecules(i, 2), Molecules(i, 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = Molecules(i, 5)

   Next j

   i = i + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

I get an error trying to use the *values of the array* for the address of the new found cells. What is wrong with the code?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: This is starting to feel like a homework task http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819421/vba-determine-if-two-or-more-cells-overlap-in-the-same-cell-address/38826947#38826947

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare something so that c knows that it needs to look through.

like example:

```
Dim rCell as Range
for each rCell in c.Cells
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not by my PC to check it out but I noticed the following:

- `For Each c In Worksheets("Main Screen")`

  should be

  ```
  For Each c In Worksheets("Main Screen").Cells
  ```
- `i = i + 1`

  should be erased, being it inside a `For i = 1 To UBound(Molecules)` loop that is already updating the iterator
- `Cells(Molecules(i, 2), Molecules(i, 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = Molecules(i, 5)`

  is inside the `For j = 1 To UBound(Molecules, 2)` loop where it produces the same results at every iteration being it dependant on `i` variable only: looks like it should be taken out of that loop and placed in the outer one.

Comment: @Toffes: did you get through it?